# Mysql - No textual descriptions of errors

Tags: mysql, mamp

I've just installed MySQL 5.7.18 with MAMP, it works fine, but error messages only contain error codes, not textual descriptions.

For example, if I try to describe a table that does not exist:

```
desc non_existent_table
```

It just shows:

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Unknown error 1146

How can I enable more descriptive error messages?

Comment: Does `perror 1146` in the command line shows an error message like `Table '%-.192s.%-.192s' doesn't exist`?

Comment: No, that is exactly the problem, it only shows: `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Unknown error 1146`

Comment: What is the output you get when you run `perror 1146` in the command line?

Comment: Ah sorry, looks like I misunderstood your question. The output is: `ERROR 1064 (42000):`

Answer (score 0):

Found this on web MySQL Server Error Codes and Messages

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html